# Laravel form model binding with dropdown thats populated form table

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

I have a form in Laravel 5.1 that uses a dropdown menu that is populated form a db table. When the form is in edit mode I want the dropdown menu item to be selected that matches the id that is already in the table in addition to the other results from the db table.

Company table

```
array([ 'id' => 1, 'name' => 'ABC Company', 'lead' => 2]);
```

Lead table

```
array([ 
    array(['id' => 1, 'lead_name' => 'Yellow Pages']),
    array(['id' => 2, 'lead_name' => 'Internet']),
    array(['id' => 3, 'lead_name' => 'Other'])
]);
```

CompanyController.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $data = Company::where('id', $id)->first();
    $leads = Lead::lists('lead_name', 'id');
    return view('company.edit', compact('data', 'leads'));
}
```

company/edit.blade.php

```
{!! Form::model($data, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'action' => ['CompanyController@update', $data->id], 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) !!}
{!! Form::select('leads', $leads, null, ['class' => 'selectpicker']) !!}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is when I edit id '1' I want the dropdown menu to show id '2' selected with he value of 'Internet' and then obviously the user can select the other 2 options and then update the table like normal.

Is it possible to use model binding in addition to a dropdown menu? Currently the menu populates but does not have id 2 selected.

Comment: You said: "Currently the menu populates but does not have id 2 selected". But what value from dropdown menu is selected now?

Comment: @FreeLightman whatever the first item is in the dropdown list, as if it was a blank html form with no selected attribute

Comment: Here `Form::select('leads', (...)` you have name `leads`. But in the table name is `lead`. Maybe this is the problem. Can you change it?

Comment: That did it. I was so concerned about the dropdown list populating from a table that I missed the basic step that form model binding uses to match the table column to the form name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

1) Did you close the form properly with `Form::close` ?

2) It seems your `$leads` array may be backward.  Should it not be?:

`$leads = Lead::lists('id', 'lead_name');`

Comment: It's not backwards since the 'key' (`id` in this case) is actually the second argument for the `lists` method.

Comment: @djt Yes I use the form close tag